# Monkey patching Flask-mail's send function

Tags: python, flask, monkeypatching, flask-mail

I am wondering if this is even the best approach, but the Flask-Mail extension accepts some `SMTP` server configs, and calls the `send` function of the `Mail` class anytime an email is to be sent.

I am using an `SMTP` provider, and have written my own send function, that leverages the Message object of the Flask-Mail extension, and now I would like to patch the mail object to use this custom function.

I've tried the following:

```
from flask_mail import Mail
#override the send email to use 
#the elastic email
Mail.send = _custom_send
app = Flask(__name__)
mail = Mail()
mail.init_app(app)
```

And

```
app = Flask(__name__)
mail = Mail()
mail.send = types.MethodType(_custom_send, mail)
mail.init_app(app)
```

However, the existing `send` function of the `Mail` class is still being called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first sentence

> I am wondering if this is even the best approach

Why don't you just subclass the original `Mail` class and redefine `.send`?

```
class MyMail(Mail):
    def send(self, ...):
      ....
```